React 18 strict mode: How to create something in a useMemo and cleanup in a useEffect
In my react components and hooks I often have the following pattern:
const foo = useMemo(() => createFoo(), []);
useEffect(() => () => foo.destroy(), [foo]);

However, with strict mode in react 18, the useEffect cleanup is called twice to check if the useEffect is not missing a cleanup. But we do have a cleanup. It's just cleaning up something which was not created in a useEffect and therefore is not being recreated...
I could change my code to
const [foo, setFoo] = useState();
useEffect(() => {
  setFoo(createFoo());
  return () => foo.destroy();
}, []);

But this causes additional renders, and more importantly when this would be a hook returning foo, it would first return nothing, which is not what I want. It even goes against react's own guidelines: https://react.dev/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect .
So, how could I achieve something that makes react 18 strict mode happy while still having the same performance?

Are you aware that StrictMode is only working during development? Just wondering because you have mentioned the performance issue.

@pzaenger Of course, but that's not relevant here. The second code snippet causes additional renders in production mode due to the setState call in the useEffect. So I don't want to take a production mode performance hit just to make strictmode happy in dev mode.

What does your createFoo do, if you don't mind? Are you opposed to using React refs by any chance?

@SebaKerckhof Sounds valid :)

Build in production mode and check again, it probably only runs once

@Dominic: Are you refering to the useState inide the useEffect or the entire component? The useEffect will cause an additional render also in prod. The entire render does not always happen without strict mode, but this is not a given in concurrent mode. e.g. If a component down the chain throws a promise for example, the tree will be discarded without ever being commited.

As per the documentation:

There is no way to opt out of Strict Mode inside a tree wrapped in <StrictMode>. This gives you confidence that all components inside <StrictMode> are checked. If two teams working on a product disagree whether they find the checks valuable, they need to either reach consensus or move <StrictMode> down in the tree.

This is a workaround you can modify to fit with your use case.
function useEffectOnceInStrictMode(fn: () => () => void) {
  const hasCalled = useRef(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "development") {
      const cleanup = fn();
      return cleanup;
    }

    if (!hasCalled.current) {
      // first execution
      hasCalled.current = true
      return () => {};
    }

    // second execution
    const cleanup = fn();
    return cleanup
  }, [])
}

In production, where Strict Mode is not enabled, useEffect reverts to its original behavior. In development, It runs both the effect function once at the second execution of StrictMode.
See in action: https://playcode.io/1840400
Disclaimer:
This implementation is predicated on the constant use of StrictMode. Disabling it may lead to unintended consequences during development.

Here is a playground: https://playcode.io/1840400
